# Get accuracy from Random Forest using 'train' model

Tags: r

I have the following code to fetch accuracy from RandomForest model with 5-fold cross validation:

```
traincontrol = trainControl(method="cv", number = 5, search = "random", savePredictions = T)



tuningGrid <- expand.grid(mtry=c(2,4,6,8))



all_accuracies <- c()


model = train(label~., data=training_data, method="rf", trControl = traincontrol,
              tuneGrid = tuningGrid, ntree = 25)
```

I plan to run this model 15 times and record the best accuracy for each time in all_accuracies. Is there any way to fetch the accuracy with code instead of manually noting it? Since if I can do that, I'll just use for loop and record every accuracy in the all_accuracies vector.

Right now, I have to write 15 lines of the same code and then record the best accuracy manually.

Comment: This sounds like there's another underlying misunderstanding. Why would you run the exact same code 15 times?

Comment: @Oliver I wanted to refit the model 15 times to obtain 15 cross validated accuracy scores and then run a t.test to check for chance. 

I have figured how to do it though now! I can use max(model$results$accuracy) to check for the maximum accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I figured how I can do it.

I can calculate maximum accuracy of a model by

```
max(model$results$accuracy)
```